# Django/Python POST

Tags: python, django, post

First a bit of an introduction. I will send a POST to a url and it will have either
ip, mac or hostname. Now depending on which of these key' are in the QueryDict i want it to do certain calls. I.e:

Output of

```
print request.POST

<QueryDict: {u'ip': [u'10.1.24.178'], u'message': [u'Test'], u'client': [u'auabrthin1']}>
```

I want to write something like this:

```
if request.POST['client'] in request.POST:
    do_something()
```

however `request.POST['client']` obviously is the value of client how can I check if a request.POST has a key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if 'client' in request.POST:
    # do something
```

Comment: Yeah, just saw it in [Django docu][https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects], Thanks anyway @ThiefMaster

Comment: Yep... the `request.POST` is just a standard [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: @jro: `request.POST` _behaves_ in many cases like a standard `dict`, but is in fact a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects). It can, for example, have multiple values for the same key.

Comment: @lazerscience: indeed, which is what I meant, but I see now that I worded it incorrectly.